# Java, is this an endless loop?

Tags: java, android

Ok, I am looking at the snippet of code below. I see a class instance being created: `recorder = new AudioRecord(...` then I see a call to the method we are already inside of `recorder.startRecording();` isn't this an endless loop. How can this be a working piece of code?

```
    private void startRecording(){//<--** this method is called from below **

                recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

                recorder.startRecording();//<--already in this method, endless loop???

                isRecording = true;               
                recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {                       
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                writeAudioDataToFile();
                        }
                },"AudioRecorder Thread");              
                recordingThread.start();
        }
```

Comment: Looks like recording and writing are done on two separate threads.  Why do you think it's endless?  Doesn't the writing thread stop when there's no more data to write?

Comment: Is your `private void startRecording()` method inside the AudioRecord class? Maybe it's a different class?
Edit: Ofcourse it has to be a different class because it starts with `private` which means you won't be able to call this method on an object.

Comment: Can you show us more code, perhaps where `recorder` is defined

Comment: Is `startRecording()` inside of the `AudioRecord` class? If yes, then its an infinite loop. If no, then it might not be. Btw, it is a different method as @chuthan20 stated. So it's two different methods in different places.

Comment: This is the [code](https://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/AudioRecorder.2/src/com/varma/samples/audiorecorder/RecorderActivity.java) I am looking at.

Comment: Well, @chuthan20 answered it faster. Thumbs up :)

Comment: Got it, Thanks. Ok, so what's the protocol on this? chuthan20.. you wanna post your answer so I can accept, or... should the accept just go to Ross?

Comment: Ross's answer is correct. You can accept his.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @chuthan20 pointed out and referencing the [given code](https://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/AudioRecorder.2/src/com/varma/samples/audiorecorder/RecorderActivity.java), the method above is from `RecorderActivity` while it is calling the method (of the same name) in `AudioRecord` so no, not recursive, not an endless loop, just happens that two classes have methods of the same name.

```
public class RecorderActivity extends Activity {
  ...     
  private AudioRecord recorder = null;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the full code (context is everything!), no, this is not an infinite loop.  The Activity's local (private) startRecording method is creating an instance of the AudioRecord class and calling that object's startRecording method.  Two different classes.